# nestjs monorepo "Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null"

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I get a `Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null` error in a nestjs monorepo only when the app is started with `npx nest start <application name>`

Anyone had this problem before ?

```
export class Boiler extends AssetBase {
                            ^
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\apps\world1\src\assets\boiler.ts:13:29)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\apps\world1\src\assets\asset-base.ts:5:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
```

** ***edit*** **

Contrary to what I thought before, I also get the error when the app is started with 'npx nest start`, the default startup project was not what I thought it to be.

I tried to debug the class hierarchy, looked for circular dependencies but I'm pretty sure there's none.

I've been looking around on the internet for this specific error message. It seems to appear in different circumstances.  It's a compile time error, not a runtime error.

Here's the `nest-cli.json` file

```json
{
  "monorepo": true,
  "root": "apps/world1",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/world1/src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "webpack": false,
    "tsConfigPath": "apps/world1/tsconfig.app.json"
  },
  "projects": {
    "controller1": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/controller1",
      "entryFile": "main",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/controller1/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/controller1/tsconfig.app.json"
      }
    },
    "dtos": {
      "type": "library",
      "root": "libs/dtos",
      "entryFile": "index",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/dtos/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "libs/dtos/tsconfig.lib.json"
      }
    },
    "world1": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/world1",
      "entryFile": "main",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/world1/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/world1/tsconfig.app.json"
      }
    },
    "general": {
      "type": "library",
      "root": "libs/general",
      "entryFile": "index",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/general/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "libs/general/tsconfig.lib.json"
      }
    },
    "algorithm1": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/algorithm1",
      "entryFile": "main",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/algorithm1/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/algorithm1/tsconfig.app.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

** ***edit 2*** **

The error went away after changing aa abstract base class into an interface.  If anyone understands this, let me know, Id love to be enlightened.

```
export abstract class AssetBase {
  constructor(readonly config: AssetConfigBaseDto) {}

  abstract simulationStep(
    period: Period,
    beginState?: AssetStateBaseDto,
    controls?: AssetControlsBaseDto,
  ): AssetStepResponse
}
```

```
export interface AssetBase {
  readonly config: AssetConfigBaseDto

  simulationStep(
    period: Period,
    beginState?: AssetStateBaseDto,
    controls?: AssetControlsBaseDto,
  ): AssetStepResponse
}
```

Comment: share us your `nest-cli.json`

Comment: for me it was an issue of circular dependency.